# Add two data frame but only a few selected column and only when other column values are the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame.

df1 has index: `str`, `int`, `float1`

```
Sun, 1, 0.121
Sun, 2, 0.123
```

df2 has index: `str`, `int`, `float1`

```
Sun, 1, 0.5
Sun, 2, 0.6
```

I have to create df3 which has index: str, int, float1 from df1 and df3 by adding the float1 column of df1 and df2 together while making sure that the two rows I am adding have the same str and int value.

df3 should look like

```
Sun, 1, 0.621
Sun, 2, 0.723
```

Thank you!

Comment: merge then sum ..

Comment: @Wen-Ben Do you mind give me a bit more details? I am new on this. Do I do a native merge of two df and then the summation can turn two columns into one?

Comment: @Wen-Ben. I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Saying `index` is confusing as `index` refers to the row labels in Pandas land.  Did you mean 3 columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use concat to merge them together and then use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `sum()` as the aggrigation method

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Sun', 1, 0.121],['Sun', 2, 0.123]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Sun', 1, 0.5],['Sun', 2, 0.6]])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(df)
#      0  1      2
# 0  Sun  1  0.121
# 1  Sun  2  0.123
# 0  Sun  1  0.500
# 1  Sun  2  0.600

print(df.groupby([0, 1], as_index=False).sum())
#      0  1      2
# 0  Sun  1  0.621
# 1  Sun  2  0.723
```

The `df.groupby()` works by passing the columns you want to use for grouping and what order. In this case, I don't have column names, so I passed integers to indicate the column positions. The `as_index` parameter will tell it to not try to reindex the dataframe with the grouped columns. The `df.groupby()` will return a `DataFrameGroupBy` object. By passing it to the `.sum()` function, it will return a dataframe with the results you are looking for.

```
gb = df.groupby([0, 1], as_index=False)
print(gb)
# <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000109A4A8>

print(gb.sum())
#      0  1      2
# 0  Sun  1  0.621
# 1  Sun  2  0.723

print(gb.mean())
#      0  1       2
# 0  Sun  1  0.3105
# 1  Sun  2  0.3615
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at each detailed step.  Can you shed some light on whatever df.groupby([0,1]) returns? Like can I see the content of the newly grouped data frame?

Comment: Would it be like Sun, 1, {0.121,0.5}; Sun, 2, {0.123, 0.6} ? And the method .sum() is applied to {0.121,0.5} and {0.123, 0.6}?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(['col_str', 'col_int'], as_index=False).sum()
```

---

```
print(df)
  col_str  col_int  col_float1
0     Sun        1       0.621
1     Sun        2       0.723
```